# Comma-separated string to NSArray in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nsarray, csv

So I have no experience with arrays... But I need to use one to populate a UIPickerView. I am obtaining a list of objects via HTTP (NSURLConnection). This works fine. Currently, the response is stored in a NSString as a comma-separated list. I need to convert it to an array. I think this is the type of array I need:

```
NSArray  * myArray2 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"foo",@"bar",@"baz",nil];
```

Maybe I'm overcomplicating things... I'm really not sure. There is already an array for the PickerView, and I have it setup so to add an item to the PickerView array I use this code:

```
[pickerArray addObject:@"Item 1"];
```

So... How do I separate the items in a comma-separated string (item 1,item 2,item 3,...) into separate array items ([pickerArray addObject:@"item 1"];)??

Answer (score 141):

Assuming there's no worry about escaping/unescaping commas contained within the strings, it should be this simple:

```
NSArray *items = [theString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

Comment: So that code will create an array from the comma-separated string?

Comment: Yes, as explained in the documentation for NSString: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html

Comment: It's late atm and I forgot about this method, it always makes me wonder why some answers aren't chosen as the correct answer.

Comment: @RickvanderLinde I think especially with inexperienced StackOverflow users, they just don't know or forget that they should accept an answer to their question. Oh well...

Comment: How would I take a comma separated value NSString = "15.009483, -87.485195" and separate them into coordinate values to plot?

Comment: @marciokoko, you should ask a new question about that.

Answer (score 0):

**Objective-C**

```
NSString *list = @"Karin, Carrie, David";
NSArray *listItems = [list componentsSeparatedByString:@", "];
```